# XML::Simple output element order from complex hash

Tags: xml, perl, sorting, xml-simple

I have already seen few answers on various places, in regards to setting the order of XML elements being returned by `XMLout`. However, I am not able to solve a problem using those answers/examples.

I have a script that needs to output some XML data, and certain elements need to be printed in certain order. Hash is pretty complex, and I was not able to achieve any results by overriding `sorted_keys` in `XML::Simple` object. Well, I did, but not in the way I wanted.

Sample code is below, details on the problem are below the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Simple;

package MyXMLSimple;
use base 'XML::Simple';

sub sorted_keys
{
 my ($self, $name, $hashref) = @_;
 # ... 
 return $self->SUPER::sorted_keys($name, $hashref);
}

package main;

my $xmlParser = MyXMLSimple->new;

my $items = {
 'status' => 'OK',
 'fields' => {
  'i1' => {
   'header' => 'Header 1',
   'max_size' => '3'
  },
  'i2' => {
   'header' => 'Header 2',
   'max_size' => '8'
  }
 },
 'item_list' => {
  'GGG' => {
   'index' => '3',
   'i' => 3,
   'points' => {
    'p5' => {
     'data' => '10',
    }
   },
  },
  'AAA' => {
   'index' => '1',
   'i' => 2,
   'points' => {
    'p7' => {
     'data' => '22',
    }
   },
  },
  'ZZZ' => {
   'index' => '2',
   'i' => 1,
   'points' => {
    'p6' => {
     'data' => '15',
    }
   },
  }
 }
};

my $xml = $xmlParser->XMLout($items);
print "$xml";
```

So, the output of this script will be this:

```
<opt status="OK">
  <fields name="i1" header="Header 1" max_size="3" />
  <fields name="i2" header="Header 2" max_size="8" />
  <item_list name="AAA" i="2" index="1">
    <points name="p7" data="22" />
  </item_list>
  <item_list name="GGG" i="3" index="3">
    <points name="p5" data="10" />
  </item_list>
  <item_list name="ZZZ" i="1" index="2">
    <points name="p6" data="15" />
  </item_list>
</opt>
```

`item_list` elements are printed out, and output order is alphabetically, by sorting on `name` attribute. Output order is AAA, GGG, ZZZ.

However, what I would need is to have the output while being sorted (numerically, from lowest to highest) on `i` element. So that output will be in order ZZZ, AAA, GGG.

I have no control over order in the hash (not without using `Tie::...` module), so I can not do it that way. If I use `NoSort => 1`, output will not be sorted by anything in particular, so I'll end up getting random output.

So, I am pretty sure that there must be a way to sort this out the way I want it by overriding `sorted_keys` subroutine. However, I couldn't get results I wanted, because `sorted_keys` gets invoked for each instance of `item_list`. When `sorted_keys` is invoked for `opt` element, then I simply have access to whole hash reference, but again no means to guarantee output ordering without relying on `Tie::` module.

Now, I have managed to get this to work the way I want, by using `Tie::IxHash` module, then overriding `sorted_keys` and (re)creating a subhash `item_list`, by reinserting values from original hash into new (ordered) one, then deleting subhash in original hash, and substituting it with new ordered hash.

Something like this:

```
sub sorted_keys
{
 my ($self, $name, $hashref) = @_;
 if ($name eq "opt")
 {
  my $clist = { };
  tie %{$clist}, "Tie::IxHash";

  my @sorted_keys = sort { $hashref->{item_list}->{$a}->{i} <=> $hashref->{item_list}->{$b}->{i} } keys %{$hashref->{item_list}};
  foreach my $sorted_key (@sorted_keys)
  {
   $clist->{$sorted_key} = $hashref->{item_list}->{$sorted_key};
  }

  delete $hashref->{item_list};
  $hashref->{item_list} = $clist;
 }
 return $self->SUPER::sorted_keys($name, $hashref);
}
```

Although this works (and so far seems to work reliably), I do believe that there must be a way to achieve this without using `Tie::IxHash` module and doing all that hash recreation/reordering, and only by somehow sorting/returning certain data from within `sorted_keys`.

I just can't figure it out, and I don't really understand how `sorted_keys` is supposed to work (especially when you get different results with different/complex sets of input data ;), but I hope there is someone out there who knows this.

I mean, I have tried modifying `XML/Simple.pm` itself and changing sort order in the last return line of `sorted_keys` subroutine, but I was still getting alphanumerically sorted output. I am afraid I can't figure out how I would modify it so it doesn't sort on `name` but on `i`.

Comment: TLDR, bit +1 for thoroughness of (IMHO, futile) effort - would have done +2 if I could :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe at this point you have outgrown XML::Simple. If you care about the order of children in an element, then it's time to use a more XML-ish module. For the style of XML creation you want, maybe [XML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-TreeBuilder/), look at the `new_from_lol` method. Or XML::LibXML, XML::Twig, XML::Writer...

I also have tried mixing Tie::IxHash and XML::Simple in the past, and it wasn't pretty. you actually got pretty far here. But I believe this way lies madness

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at overriding hash_to_array? Worked out for me.
http://perlmaven.com/xml-simple-sorting

I wanted to perform a natural sort against a tag key and managed to achieve by overriding XML::Simple hash_to_array. I basically copied the method from XML::Simple.pm and made a small edit for the natural sort - like this:

```
package MyXMLSimple;      # my XML::Simple subclass
use base 'XML::Simple';

sub hash_to_array {
  my $self    = shift;
  my $parent  = shift;
  my $hashref = shift;

  my $arrayref = [];

  my($key, $value);

  if ( $parent eq "mytag" ) {
  my @keys = $self->{opt}->{nosort} ? keys %$hashref : sort {$a<=>$b} keys %$hashref;
  foreach $key (@keys) {
    $value = $hashref->{$key};
    return($hashref) unless(UNIVERSAL::isa($value, 'HASH'));

    if(ref($self->{opt}->{keyattr}) eq 'HASH') {
      return($hashref) unless(defined($self->{opt}->{keyattr}->{$parent}));
      push @$arrayref, $self->copy_hash(
        $value, $self->{opt}->{keyattr}->{$parent}->[0] => $key
      );
    }
    else {
      push(@$arrayref, { $self->{opt}->{keyattr}->[0] => $key, %$value });
    }
  }

  } else {
  my @keys = $self->{opt}->{nosort} ? keys %$hashref : sort keys %$hashref;
  foreach $key (@keys) {
    $value = $hashref->{$key};
    return($hashref) unless(UNIVERSAL::isa($value, 'HASH'));

    if(ref($self->{opt}->{keyattr}) eq 'HASH') {
      return($hashref) unless(defined($self->{opt}->{keyattr}->{$parent}));
      push @$arrayref, $self->copy_hash(
        $value, $self->{opt}->{keyattr}->{$parent}->[0] => $key
      );
    }
    else {
      push(@$arrayref, { $self->{opt}->{keyattr}->[0] => $key, %$value });
    }
  }
  }

  return($arrayref);
}

my $xmlParser = MyXMLSimple->new(KeepRoot => 1);
$xmlParser->XMLout($self->{_xml}, KeyAttr => { ...
```

Sure, it's ugly, sentinel would need to set 'i' as KeyAttr and its 5 years too late but it works and now I can go do something else :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes